# Launching an activity from the ListView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, listactivity

```
public class ListItem
{   
public int sname;
public int s_img;
public String sid; 
}


Class xyz extends ListActivity
{
.
.
.
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{

       //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);     
      Toast.makeText(ListPage.this,items.get(position).sid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),DisplayScheme.class);
      startActivityForResult(intent,0);
}
}
```

I wish to start a new Activity from the above xyz class. The Activity should start when one of the items on the list is clicked. In the next Activity, I wish to display further details of the "ListItem" object viz. s_img and sname;
Is there a way by which I could pass on the CLICKED ListItem object to the next DisplayScheme activity ? coz there is no way in the next Activity to find out which item was clicked in the earlier activity. Thanks in advance.

.............. edited ...............

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {

    //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);        
    Toast.makeText(ListPage.this, items.get(position).sid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),DisplayScheme.class);
    intent.putExtra("positionIdentifier",v.getTag());
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
    }
```

this is my edited onListItemClick. Now I am getting an error on the "intent.putextra" line which says "The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Object)"

................. more edits.. arrayadapter................

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{  

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<ListItem> items;

public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<ListItem> items) 
{  
    super();

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override  
public int getCount() 
{  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return items.size();  
}  

@Override  
public Object getItem(int position) 
{  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) 
{  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}

@Override  
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{  

    ListItem item = items.get(position);
    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    ImageView imgv = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.s_name); 
    imgv.setImageResource(item.sname);                
    return vi;  
}
}
```

this is my MyAdapter class, where exactly do I need to make changes like "setTag()" or something like dat ?

Comment: whats wrong with eh above? any exceptions?

Comment: no errors... just wanted to know how to pass the entire clicked object to the next activity.

Comment: @AbhijeetLimaye BTW you might need to accept the answers which solved your problems. There is not even a single answer that you accepted out of the six questions you have asked.

Comment: @Raghunandan: pardon my stupidity, but I'm really new to stackoverflow..... Wat exactly do I do to accept an answer ? :p

Comment: You just need to click on the tick mark next to the answer that solved your problem. When you accept it, it changes to green color which resembles that it is an accepted answer which in turn would help others to find the quick answer who refer this later.

Comment: @Raghunandan: got it... ! I'll do it for all my questions as soon as my current doubt is solved :)

Comment: @AbhijeetLimaye you are tagging a wrong person. It's me appu who said that.

Comment: @Appu: sorry my bad :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, mostly looks good:

```
Toast.makeText(ListPage.this,items.get(position).sid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),DisplayScheme.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

But, instead of using the `v.getContext()` I would suggest using this: `xyz.this`.

Also, if you are not expecting a result back from the `DisplayScheme` Activity, there is no need to use `startActivityForResult()`. you should use just the `startActivity()` and pass the  `intent` instance to it.

If you need to send data with the `Intent`, a simple `intent.putExtra(SOME_KEY_NAME, THE_VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO SEND);` will do it for you.

You don't need to use `startActivityForResult()` if you want to send data to another Activity. You use it when you want to fetch some result back from another Activity.

EDIT:

Okay, so in the Activity you should also have the corresponding `List<ListItem> items;` to gather the data and pass to the Adapter right? You still haven't posted that code for the Activity. But see if this helps. You may have to play around to get it right.

```
Toast.makeText(ListPage.this,items.get(position).sid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),DisplayScheme.class);
intent.putExtra("SOME_KEY_NAME", items.get(position).sname;
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

If you are using a POJO (*a setter and getter*) to handle the data before passing it to the `List<ListItem> items;`, posting that and as much details from the Activity as you can would help even more.

Comment: intent.putExtra("item",items[position]);

I just added above line, but I get an error which says "the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List[ListItem]"

Comment: Posting your Adapter would help perhaps. Your post does not show how you handle the data between the ListView and the Adapter. Without seeing them, there is not much to go with.

Comment: no not yet :(

the thing is, the ListItem object has three fields, (string,int,int). In the inflated list, I'm displaying ONLY one(of the two) image and in the next DisplayScheme activity, I wish to show ONLY the OTHER image(of the two) please tell me wat would be the best way to do that

Comment: @AbhijeetLimaye: I am sorry. But I understood nothing from your comment. Could you please elaborate a little? Especially: _I wish to show ONLY the OTHER image(of the two)_

Comment: in the inflated list I'm displaying only the "sname" image for the ListItem object. In the next DisplayScheme activity, I wish to display nothing other than the "s_img" image from the CLICKED object in the list.

Comment: @AbhijeetLimaye: You can just change the `items.get(position).sname` to `items.get(position).something_else`. If that is the only issue, this should fix it.

Comment: yes I already changed it to "s_img", but in the next Activity, how to I get this using the "intent.getStringExtra("s_img");" method ? where and how exactly should I write this line and use the s_img ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. You can use `setTag()` to keep an identifier for each list item in your `getView()` method of your adapter like `setTag(position)`. So you can get the tag from the view in the `onClick()` method and then send it to the next activity with extras like `intent.putExtra("positionIdentifier",view.getTag());`

Comment: Can you show me the code where did you keep the tag or post your full activity code?

Comment: do I first need to "setTag()" or somethin like dat in order to use this "getTag()" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put some data when you start activity

This part must be in OnItemClickListener

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, ActivityForStart.class);
intent.putExtra("name_of_variable", variable);
startActivity(intent);
```

in new activity

```
intent.getStringExtra("name_of_variable")));
```

Comment: where and how exactly do I have to write "intent.getString..." in the next activity ?

Answer (score 0):

it considers v.getTag() as a object. if you have tag value as a string then you have to cast in string and pass value by putting ".toString()" after v.getTag().

Note : its only for String passing. you can do the same for other values by casting.

Answer (score 0):

> this is my edited onListItemClick. Now I am getting an error on the
>   "intent.putextra" line which says "The method putExtra(String,
>   boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments
>   (String, Object)"

this is because the getTag() returns an object, and this is because you can put there whatever you wish.

if you've put there a boolean, just put a cast on it and you are ready to go.

if you've put there something else (like a viewHolder), decide what you wish to put and cast it instead.

---

here's a simple modification for your code to work:

in the adapter:

```
@Override  
public ListItem getItem(int position) 
  {  
  return items.get(position);
  }  

@Override  
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {  
  ListItem item = getItem(position);
  //... same as before, but please use viewHolder
  }
```

outside the adapter , in the activity "xyz" (which you should rename to have an uppercase letter btw):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
  {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);     
  Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayScheme.class);
  intent.putExtra("selectedImageToShow",_adapter.getItem(position).s_img);
  startActivityForResult(intent,0);
  }
```

Comment: do I first need to "setTag()" or somethin like dat in order to use this "getTag()" ?

Comment: if you have never called setTag on the view, when you call getTag on it you will get null (otherwise how would it know what you want to get from it). the tag can be used for anything to "attach" to the view. it's usually used for viewHolder in listView. watch "the world of listView" for more information of this: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Comment: do you wish to send the selected object to the next activity? if so , you can either implement and use the getItem() method in the adapter, or set the item for each viewHolder you use. however, sending the object to another activity depends on the type of the object, and if it's a customized one (for example a class with a string and an integer) you need to make it parcelable . here's a tutorial: http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/09/a-parcelable-tutorial-for-android.html . also please watch the video i've told you about. it will make things a bit cleared about listView.

Comment: I think sending an object is not really necessary, sending just the "int s_img" (which is an image) will do.

Comment: if by "an image" you mean a bitmap, it would be a problem. if you mean it's the resource id of the image, or a path to it, then it's ok.

Comment: the thing is, the ListItem object has three fields, (string,int,int). In the inflated list, I'm displaying ONLY one(of the two) image and in the next DisplayScheme activity, I wish to show ONLY the OTHER image(of the two)

please tell me wat would be the best way to do that.

Comment: so just past the other image of the two to the next activity. i think what you are doing is like thumbnails vs full screen image, is this correct? again, there are many solutions for this, and i've presented you 2 of them. are you sure you've watched the video?

Comment: ok i've updated my answer to have one of the solutions i've offered.